# Qt 5.3 QTreeWidget::setHeaderLabels segfaults

Tags: c++, linux, qt, segmentation-fault

I am subclassing a QTreeWidget and here is my contstructor

```
MyTreeWidget::MyTreeWidget() : QTreeWidget(){
    prepareHeader();
    setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
}
```

And the `MyTreeWidget::prepareHeader()` function is:

```
void MyTreeWidget::prepareHeader(){
    this->setColumnCount(2);
    QStringList columTitles;
    columTitles << "Type" << "Name";

    //This segfaults
    this->setHeaderLabels(columTitles);
}
```

My code segfaults when I call `this->setHeaderLabels(columTitles)`. 
I am compiling in Ubuntu Linux with Qt 5.3

Comment: The code seems right. Did you check in a debugger where exactly it is segfaulting?

Comment: Ok, the code is right. The segmentation fault comes from another part of my application which is openGL based. So this question is solved.